# Unable to get file meta data information in Llama index

Tags: llama-index

I am unable to extract metadata information from the documents. PFB my code

```
filename_fn = lambda filename: {'file_name': filename}
documents = SimpleDirectoryReader("../data", file_metadata=filename_fn).load_data()
print([x for x in documents])
```

It's printing the empty array. I have a few documents in the data folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your code just works fine for me, maybe your folder path can cause this.

I am on llama_index -> 0.7.4

[image: here]

[image]